# Modelmapper: Map an element in a list to field in POJO

Tags: java, mapping, dto, modelmapper

```
public class SimpleDTO{
    private String firstElement;
    private String lastElement;
}

public class ComplexSource{
    private List<String> elementList;
}
```

I tried to map it using`map().setFirstElement(source.getElementList().get(0))` but I get an error stating "1) Invalid source method java.util.List.get(). Ensure that method has zero parameters and does not return void."

How do I map an element in a list to a field in a Pojo using ModelMapper or any other alternative?

Answer (score 6):

In this case is you can't use a `PropertyMap`. If you want map it using `ModelMapper` you must use a `Converter` instead of `PropertyMap` as you have done.

First your Converter would be as next where the `source` is `ComplexSource` and `SimpleDTO` is the destination:

```
Converter<ComplexSource, SimpleDTO> converter = new AbstractConverter<ComplexSource, SimpleDTO>() {
    @Override
    protected SimpleDTO convert(ComplexSource source) {
        SimpleDTO destination = new SimpleDTO();
        List<String> sourceList = source.getElementList();

        if(null != sourceList && !sourceList.isEmpty()){
            int sizeList = sourceList.size();

            destination.setFirstElement(sourceList.get(0));
            destination.setLastElement(sourceList.get(sizeList - 1));
        }

        return destination;
    }
};
```

Then you just need to add the converter to your `ModelMapper` instance:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.addConverter(converter);
```

If you try the map, it works perfectly:

```
ComplexSource complexSource = new ComplexSource();
complexSource.setElementList(Arrays.asList("firstElement", "lastElement"));

SimpleDTO simpleDto = mapper.map(complexSource, SimpleDTO.class);
System.out.println(simpleDto);
```

**Output**

> SimpleDTO [firstElement=firstElement, lastElement=lastElement]

---

Respect your comment, you need to check nulls if it is need in your source instance (in this case it is possible a null pointer if the list is null). But it inits for you the destination instance, even you can configure the destination instance how you want with a `Provider` ([Providers documentation](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#providers)).

In cases of special use cases like this, you need to worry about null checks and exceptions handling because a `Converter` I would say is the way of modelmapper to map manually pojos.

The advantadges of use ModelMapper are explained in its web:

- If you configure it correctly in some cases it is no need to do the map manually.
- It centralizes the mapping.
- It provides a mapping API for handling special use cases. (This is your case)
- And so on (take a look its [web](http://modelmapper.org/))

Comment: Thanks! Tangential question, whats the advantage of using a ModelMapper vs using a simple mapper method to convert one object to another? I assumed that I wouldn't have to worry about the null checks and exception handling with a third party mapper, but seems like I am wrong on my assumption.

Comment: @Matrix I've answered in the post your comment